# Is there a way to isolate the elements of list without using a for loop?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to make a basic Python program where a user inputs a number at random, and if it matches one of the numbers in a list they get a printed "congratulations". And if not, they get to choose again.

[image: line 5 of this code is my problem]

My problem is, I don't know how isolate the elements of this list without using a `for` loop.

For example, suppose I have a list: `numbers = [1, 9, 8,33,78,89,235]`. And I also have a `UserInput` function that will allow the user to select any number.

I don't understand how to properly code `if UserInput == an *element in numbers*: print("congratulations")`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please don't upload your code as an image, but do paste it here. The editor allows you to add code blocks with the {} button.

Comment: You can use the "in" keyword, but it will still loop - it just does it behind the scenes. If you're avoiding looping for performance and your list has a lot of elements, you might consider a hash table or dict instead.

Comment: @kgiannakakis Will make sure to do this next time. Thank you!

Comment: Just use `if UserInput() in numbers:`.

Answer (score 1):

##### This is how you do it:-

```py
numbers = [1, 9, 8,33,78,89,235]
user_input = int(input("Enter a number: "))
if user_input in numbers:
    print("Correct answer")
else:
    print("Wrong answer")
```